# MySQL return month by month count for each distinct ID

Tags: mysql

I wrote the below query, which works, but it is incredibly inefficient and slow.  What can I do to make it more efficient?  I understand that it's basically "looping" over each ID in the system, there's about 500 of them, and running 13 select statements for each one - I just don't know a better way to get this information.

My date field is a `DATE` field stored as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

```
SELECT 
id as name,
 (SELECT sum(captured_profit) from me where (date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31') and id = name)  as January,
 (SELECT sum(captured_profit) from me where (date BETWEEN '2017-02-01' AND '2017-02-31') and id = name)  as February,
 (SELECT sum(captured_profit) from me where (date BETWEEN '2017-03-01' AND '2017-03-31') and id = name)  as March,
 (SELECT sum(captured_profit) from me where (date BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-31') and id = name)  as April,
 (SELECT sum(captured_profit) from me where (date BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-31') and id = name)  as May,
 (SELECT sum(captured_profit) from me where (date BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-06-31') and id = name)  as June,
 (SELECT sum(captured_profit) from me where (date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-31') and id = name)  as July,
 (SELECT sum(captured_profit) from me where (date BETWEEN '2017-08-01' AND '2017-08-31') and id = name)  as August,
 (SELECT sum(captured_profit) from me where (date BETWEEN '2017-09-01' AND '2017-09-31') and id = name)  as September,
 (SELECT sum(captured_profit) from me where (date BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31') and id = name)  as October,
 (SELECT sum(captured_profit) from me where (date BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-31') and id = name)  as November,
 (SELECT sum(captured_profit) from me where (date BETWEEN '2017-12-01' AND '2017-12-31') and id = name)  as December,
 (SELECT sum(captured_profit) from me where (date BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-12-31') and id = name)  as Total,
from me
where id is not null
group by id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate functions like SUM() ignore NULLs. So use an expression to make the profit value NULL unless it falls within the range you want.

```
SELECT 
  id AS name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 1 THEN captured_profit END) AS January,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 2 THEN captured_profit END) AS February,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 3 THEN captured_profit END) AS March,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 4 THEN captured_profit END) AS April,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 5 THEN captured_profit END) AS May,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 6 THEN captured_profit END) AS June,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 7 THEN captured_profit END) AS July,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 8 THEN captured_profit END) AS August,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 9 THEN captured_profit END) AS September,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 10 THEN captured_profit END) AS October,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 11 THEN captured_profit END) AS November,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 12 THEN captured_profit END) AS December,
  SUM(captured_profit) AS Total
FROM me
WHERE id IS NOT NULL AND YEAR(date) = 2017
GROUP BY id;
```

The `CASE` expression returns NULL if there's no match and no `ELSE` clause. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html for more details.

This query eliminates all the correlated subqueries. The query will scan through the table just once.

---

I don't know what the meaning of your "Total" is in your query, but it appears to be just November + December. I'm not sure if that's what you intended.

Edit: I fixed the expression for Total.

Comment: it means I was typing fast and did `11` instead of `01`.  Thanks :)  Let me try this out and let you know, thank you so much!  Edit: Booya, this is EXACTLY what I needed.  I'll read up on CASE statements!

Comment: Okay then the Total can be simply `SUM(captured_profit)` in my example, since I used a WHERE condition to limits the range to 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Simply group by year, month and id

```
select id, sum(captured_profit), month( `date`)
from me 
where id is not null and `date` > '2016-12-31'
group by year(`date`), month(`date`), id;
```

I guess you didn't use all the keywords (name, date) as your actual column names, if you did make sure to put them in backticks in every query.

Comment: Hmm... this is just giving me back one sum - it's not breaking it down month by month.  I did use `date` as the name for my date column, so I'll put it in backticks.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Just also put month(date) in the selection. If you want the month's name, you can use the monthname() function. @BrianPowell

Comment: yeah, I tried that as well... no luck.  Does my `date` field need to be something other than MySQL `DATE`?  Like `DATETIME` or something?

Comment: @BrianPowell  edited the answer. If you run the query you will get the corresponding month in a column

Comment: Sorry - I don't need one corresponding month - I need individual columns with summaries FOR each month.  My original SQL outputs 13 rows - 1 for January, 1 for February, etc., and then a `TOTALS` column - that's what each sub-select statement is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Bill Karwin beat me to it but I also added the sum rows grouped by year:

```
SELECT 
    id as name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 1 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS January,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 2 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS February,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 3 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS March,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 4 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS April,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 5 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS May,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 6 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS June,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 7 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS July,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 8 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS August,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 9 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS September,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 10 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS October,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 11 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS November,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 12 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS December,
    SUM(captured_profit) AS Total,
    YEAR(date)
from me
where id is not null
group by id, YEAR(date)
union
SELECT 
    NULL,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 1 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS January,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 2 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS February,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 3 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS March,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 4 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS April,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 5 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS May,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 6 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS June,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 7 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS July,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 8 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS August,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 9 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS September,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 10 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS October,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 11 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS November,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 12 THEN captured_profit ELSE 0 END) AS December,
    SUM(captured_profit) AS Total,
    YEAR(date)
from me
where id is not null
group by YEAR(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is exactly what you are looking for

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-monthname-function.php

MySQL MONTHNAME() returns the full name of the month for a given date. The return value is within the range of 1 to 12 ( January to December). It Returns NULL when month part for the date is 0 or more than 12

Syntax :

```
MONTHNAME(date1)
```

Comment: I was kind of looking for a way to re-write this query so I'm not doing 13 sub-select statements for each unique ID....  But this will be useful in converting stuff when I'm all done.  Thanks!

Comment: @brianPowell
maybe you can do like this
SELECT sum(captured_profit),monthName(date) as NAME from me Gruop by NAME
it will return serveral rows each row has the sum of each month Name